Using Mudblazor in MudDataGrid overall Filter i Want to remove TimePicker hh:mm:ss in date column filter and filter only by Date not time
I want remove hh:mm:ss TimePicker from Date column in my table overall filter. I want my filter to filter date column based only on Date picker yyyy/MM/dd
reproduction link:
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QuwIktueTUoFhTtz

as per reference to above image i want to remove the timepicker value from filter popover.

Not currently possible with the built-in filters.
Here's the feature request for it: https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/7741
You could create your own custom filter but it will be messy.
I'd recommend waiting till they add support for DateOnly & TimeOnly as mentioned in this discussion:
https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/discussions/2954
